# Unable to get tor bridges

Tags: bridge

There are simply two ways to get tor bridges:

1. sending an email to `bridges@torproject.org` with an empty subject and `get transport obfs4` as body
2. using [BridgeDB](https://bridges.torproject.org/bridges?transport=obfs4)

I can't receive bridges using either of these ways.

1. Tor autoresponder doesn't respond to my emails (I use my gmail account)
2. BridgeDB blocks me by it's captcha no matter how many times i solve the captcha it loads another one and doesn't allow me to pass.

### Edit April, 2020

Can't get responds from autoresponder. BridgeDB works as expected.
There is certainly some issues with the autoresponder.

Comment: I will report this issue to the Tor Project and open a bug if nobody else has already.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this one more time please? It seems to be working:

USING MOAT
If you're starting Tor Browser for the first time, click 'Configure' to open the Tor Network Settings window. Otherwise, click on 'Preferences' in the hamburger menu (main menu) and then on 'Tor' in the sidebar.

In the Tor Network Settings window, select 'Tor is censored in my country.' Then, select 'Request a bridge from torproject.org' and click 'Request a bridge...'

Complete the CAPTCHA and click 'Submit'.

See: https://tb-manual.torproject.org/bridges/ for more information.

Comment: thanks actually sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. In case of captcha i had to solve it 6-8 times which is really uncomforable and autoresponder takes a long time to respond. Before the service was more responsive and usable.

Comment: Nobody else has reported issues with it. I'm not sure what to say. Also, someone is looking into the email issue.

Comment: I don't know all i can say is that there is nothing automated on my side and am trying to play really nice with the service and only request a new bridge when used ones don't work anymore.

Comment: Tested now and both methods work as expected.:)

Comment: update April, 2020. Autoresponder doesn't respond again.